# Is there a way to a open a pdf with a VB function that bypass the path of the executing file (Acrobat.exe)

Tags: vba, function, shell, ms-access, adobe

I have a MS-Access database that is used by multiple users using different computer settings (Some people use Windows XP, others Windows 7 with Adobe Reader version 11.0 or 12.0, etc.). Is there a way to a open (from a command button in a form) a pdf file (using Adobe Reader) with a VB function that bypass a segment of the path of the executing file (Acrobat.exe)?

For now, I have this VB function.

```
Call Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"" ""C:\DOCUMENTS\DOCUM\SPECS\Faune_DEV\SP" & Me![Element_id] & ".pdf", 1)
```

I want something like :

```
Call Shell("""C:\GoAndGetTheAcrobat.exeFile"" ""C:\DOCUMENTS\DOCUM\SPECS\Faune_DEV\SP" & Me![Element_id] & ".pdf", 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Shell object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890(v=vs.85).aspx) to [run the file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee156605.aspx).

```
' Use Windows shell to run file.
Sub WinRun()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    shell.Run "Your-Drive:\Your-Path\Your-File.pdf"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can launch any windows file as if you double clicked on it with:

```
application.FollowHyperlink "full path name to any windows file"
```

Comment: Nice one champ!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an application program path you can use the command start.exe and it starts the default application for your file:

```
start.exe [path_to_your_pdf_file]
```

So you can try:

```
Call Shell("""start.exe"" ""C:\DOCUMENTS\DOCUM\SPECS\Faune_DEV\SP" & Me![Element_id] & ".pdf", 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Call Shell("""C:\GoAndGetTheAcrobat.exeFile"" ""C:\DOCUMENTS\DOCUM\SPECS\Faune_DEV\SP" & Me![Element_id] & ".pdf", 1)

Comment: this is the same answer as written above, just formatted more poorly